# NancyFX returning text/html from Response.AsJson

Tags: asp.net, json, azure, nancy, fluentvalidation

I'm using NancyFx in my api: v2.0-clinteastwood, Asp.net Hosted (Local: IIS Express, Remote: Aure Web App).

I'm using `Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation` (v2.0-clinteastwood) and posting a JSON object to a POST endpoint. I'm intentionally sending it an object that fails my validation requirements.

The code that does the validation and returns the result (if it fails), looks a bit like this.

```
 var validationResult = this.Validate(POCO object i bind, data here is as expected);
 if (!validationResult.IsValid)
 {
      return Response.AsJson(validationResult).WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
 }
```

When i'm running it locally, the response returned is of Content Type: `application/json` and contains the validation failure body as Json (**EXPECTED**).

When i'm running it remotely, the response returned is of Content Type: `text/html` and does **NOT** contain the validation failure body.

I've set logging across every line of code and ensured that there's no custom pipeline methods that are changing the output. I have also tried editing the return to be:

```
return Response.AsJson(validationResult).WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest).WithContentType("application/json");
```

Yet `text/html` is still returned.

I hvae replicated this in fiddler and stripped every other header. The basic request looks like this:

```
POST https://justatestdomain.com/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: justatestdomain.com
Content-Length: x

{"property1":"value 1","property2":"value2"}
```

I can also confirm my CORS headers are correctly configured.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, x-ms-request-id, x-ms-request-root-id
```

This is only happening when targeting the remote (Azure) hosted version. Can anyone explain this heaviour or suggestion other things I should investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to the Nancy Slack room. You need to ensure your web.config includes the following to allow for the Nancy pass through.

```
<system.webServer>
     <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>
```

More, specific details can be found on the [NancyFx Wiki - Custom Errors on Asp.Net](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Custom-errors-on-ASP.NET)